# zip_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given on line 37

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am creating a file to extract zip files . The code snipped checks if the file extension is .zip and then if the file already exists. If not, extract the archive.

```
    if($fileExtension == "zip")
{
    if(is_dir("unzips/".$fileName) == false)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"temp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip -> open("temp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        for($num = 0; $num < $zip->numFiles; $num++)
        {
            $fileInfo = $zip->statIndex($num);
            echo "Successfully Extracted: ".$fileInfo["name"];
            $zip->extractTo("unzips/".$fileName);
            echo "<br />";
        }

        zip_close($zip);

        unlink("temp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
    else
    {
        echo $fileName." The ZIP archive file has already been unzipped";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Only .zip files are allowed";
}
```

Here's the full code for index.php

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unzipping Zip File</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Extract">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $array = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $fileName = $array[0];
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end($array));

    if($fileExtension == "zip")
    {
        if(is_dir("unzips/".$fileName) == false)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"temp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $zip -> open("temp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

            for($num = 0; $num < $zip->numFiles; $num++)
            {
                $fileInfo = $zip->statIndex($num);
                echo "Successfully Extracted: ".$fileInfo["name"];
                $zip->extractTo("unzips/".$fileName);
                echo "<br />";
            }

            $zip -> close();

            unlink("temp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        }
        else
        {
            echo $fileName." The ZIP archive file has already been unzipped";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Only .zip files are allowed";
    }
}

?>

<br />
<p id="end note">Please return to main menu and download individually extracted files.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

directory structure looks like:
D:/MyWebs/extracting/index.php
D:/MyWebs/extracting/unzips (final destination that contains unzipped folder)
D:/MyWebs/extracting/temp (stores zip and then deletes them)

Comment: use $zip->close(); instead because zip_close() accepts a resource zip file opened with zip_open();

Comment: You have another issue in your code. You are setting an invalid value to `$fileName`, (when you get it as `$fileName = $array[0];`, you are missing the extension from it). so opening the zip file will fail. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void zip_close ( resource $zip )
>
> **zip**
>
> ```
> A ZIP file previously opened with zip_open().
> ```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.zip-close.php

`$zip` is an instance of `ZipArchive()` class. So you cannot pass that to `zip_close()` as it expects a resource created with `zip_open()`.

## ...............................................................................

**EDIT:** I noticed you have another bug in your code after you added the full source.

You have set an invalid value to `$fileName` variable.

```
$array = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$fileName = $array[0];
```

When you explode the `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`, and get only the `$array[0]` value, you are only getting the name of the file (without the extension).

So when you pass an invalid path to `$zip->open($fileName);` method, it will return you an error:

> ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Change the above to something like:

```
$array = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extractDir = $array[0];
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fileExtension = strtolower(end($array));

if(is_dir("unzips/".$extractDir) == false){
   .
   .
   $zip->extractTo("unzips/".$extractDir);
   .
   .
}
```

This will work. 
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

> `zip_close()` expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

The error message is self-explanatory.

The [documentation of `zip_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.zip-close.php) says that the argument expected by `zip_close()` should be:

> A ZIP file previously opened with [zip_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.zip-open.php).

Since you are using a [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) object you have to use its methods to handle it. In particular, [`ZipArchive::close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.close.php) is the method used to close a `ZipArchive` (previously open using [`ZipArchive::open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php) as you did).

Your code should look like:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open("temp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

// Do whatever you want with the content of the archive here (extract files, f.e.)

$zip->close();
```